# C++ Passing a wstringstream to another function

Tags: c++, function

I tried to do the following:

```
wstring wStringStreamToWString(wstringstream uStream)
{
   wstring s(uStream.str());
   return s;
}
```

This gives me the compiler error

```
"C2248 std::basic_ios>_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios: No access to private members whose declaration was done in std::basic_ios<_Elmen,_Trais>- class."
```

However, if I do not do this in a separate function, it works fine.
So I guess I am simply doing an mistake when I pass the wstringstream to the function, but I don't see which.

Can anybody help?

Thank you.

Comment: This actually compiles for me -- http://ideone.com/3w04Mq#view_edit_box

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: clang, g++ and vs2010 all accept this.

Comment: Did you write out the error message, instead of copying and pasting it? There seem to be some typos in it... You should always just copy and paste!

Comment: Try passing that stream by ***reference***: `wStringStreamToWString(wstringstream& uStream)`. Copy construction of  streams is generally not allowed, usually by making the copy-ctor of at least one class in the inheritance chain *private*. Thus your error message.

Comment: That function isn't the problem, it's the places that you use it. See this example: http://ideone.com/XS2FSU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the argument by (`const` as it is not being modified) reference as streams are not copyable:

```
wstring wStringStreamToWString(wstringstream const& uStream)
{
    wstring s(uStream.str());
    return s;
}
```

Though the function, as it stands, seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: +1, especially for picking up the `const` betterment I failed to consider in my comment. Nice.